# npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED while creatting react-app

Tags: node.js, ssl, npm, error-handling

I am facing an issue while creating react-app `npx create-react-app react-app`. Here's the error message I'm encountering:

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm ERR! errno ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint: 48090000:error:1C800066:Provider routines:ossl_gcm_stream_update:cipher operation failed:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\providers\implementations\ciphers\ciphercommon_gcm.c:320:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\KRISHNA\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-03T10_41_53_464Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.
```

I attempted to resolve this issue by performing the following steps:

1. Checked my internet connection to ensure it's stable.
2. Updated Node.js and npm to their latest versions using
   `npm install -g npm@latest`
3. Tried running the npm install command with the --verbose flag to get more detailed output.
4. Cleared the npm cache using `npm cache clean -f.`
5. Set the registry URL to HTTP instead of HTTPS using npm config set registry     http://registry.npmjs.org/.
   What I was expecting:

I was expecting that one of these steps would resolve the
`npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED` 
error, and I could successfully install the ESLint package without any SSL-related issues.